# My laptop keeps crashing irregularly

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod, crash

My laptop is a Lenovo ideapad s340
It just keeps crashing irregularly lately.

1. It overheats like crazy when I open any tab from any browser.
2. Ive already brought my laptop to a computer shop, they have cleaned the fan but nothing seems to have improved.
3. Ive already ran chkdsk on CMD but nothing has also imrpoved. (Ive ran chkdsk again but my laptop goes BSOD everytime its in Stage 4)
4. Ive optimized C:, nothing improved.
5. Ive tried to optimize my drives but it always goes BSOD
6. My average mem usage is 70-92% and cpu usage is usually at 10%
7. Ive cleaned my drives and transported them to a USB drive.
8. Ive changed my power plan.
9. The BSOD that I usually get is MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION.
10. Ive uninstalled a bunch of apps that I thought would be a virus. (I didnt touch anything in C:)
11. Ive let my antivirus do a scan for any viruses, 3-4 minutes in and the laptop goes BSOD again.
12. I run windows 10.
13. I tried to update my drivers but it goes BSOD.
14. I tried updating to win 11 but BSOD keeps appearing.

Please help.

Comment: I think you meant to say "crashes consistently at irregular intervals" in the title, because it seems like it's crashing more predictably often than "irregularly".

Answer (score 0):

You should run an in-depth memory test, and see if your memory is a little faulty.   I would also look at the S.M.A.R.T information from the hard drive and possibly run a disk check.

I would also back up my documents, wipe the system and reinstall the OS from scratch.  (not an upgrade, a complete reinstall)

I would also run a CPU stress test and watch the clock speed when you do so - if the clock speed remains low, it could be a heating issue (ie you replaced the fan, but what about the thermal paste between the heatsink and the CPU?)

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately the first and last solutions didnt work so im planning on backing up everything and reinstalling my OS

Comment: Not sure of you realise that memory and CPU stress tests should take hours/days?

Comment: @davidgo when a CPU is bad, a stress test will reveal that relatively fast. These "extended tests" are largely inflated opinions of "overclocking gurus". The only thing that's going to happen after "hours/days" is your CPU running at high temps for extended time, wasting power and wearing down fans and your ears. That type of testing is not really necessary for regular use, imho. This is a single user's laptop, not a critical routing node in an ISP's network.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Your own answer talks about 10 passes of memtest86, kind of contradicts your comment on how long testing takes.  Not sure you picked up that the time between my answer snd the comment that stress testing did not reveal anything was about an hour... Unlrss the OP had already ren stress testing but did not mention it in his question he could not have adequately stress tested the system.

Comment: @davidgo yeah I do say that memtest86 should be run overnight, but I'm not suggesting to **senselessly** burn the CPU for hours/days **just for the heck of it**. My answer talks about one pass of memtest86, consisting of 10+ stages, not 10 passes. Also, I provide a specific diagnostic tool/approach instead of asking the user if _they know that *imo* stress testing should take x amount of time_ - which is vague, and untrue (in most cases).

Comment: I know that asking for tools is off topic, but your answer is vague beyond the point of utility. "You should run an in-depth memory test." ***How?*** Do I rub the memory sticks with my hands? Polish them with a powertool?

Answer (score 0):

> Ive already brought my laptop to a computer shop, they have cleaned the fan but nothing seems to have improved.

I would not take them at their word.

> (Ive ran chkdsk again but my laptop goes BSOD everytime its in Stage 4)

That would suggest you need a new disk, or the installation is corrupted.
Or the RAM is bad, or the CPU is bad, or some other component is bad.
Consistent crashes are often due to faulty hardware.

from wikipedia.org:

> **Machine-check exception**
>
> A machine-check exception is a type of computer hardware error that occurs when a computer's central processing unit detects a hardware error in the processor itself, the memory, the I/O devices, or on the system bus; in some architectures, an MCE only occurs for an unrecoverable error.

Just boot from a usb flash-disk with [memtest86+](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm), run it overnight for one full pass (10+ stages). And if it produces errors, you need to swap hardware components out, or replace the laptop.